# Как заменить стандартное всплывающее окно на google maps, когда кликаешь на маркер?

Tags: google-maps-api

Как заменить стандартную всплывашку на google maps, когда кликаешь на маркер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не подходит [Tooltip for Google Maps API V3](https://github.com/medelbou/Tooltip-for-Google-Maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open), в Google Картах можно поменять как:

1) Самый популярный способ - с помощью [**infoBubble**](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html).

Пример использования этого infoBubble можно увидеть [на этом сайте](http://diveseven.com/atlas).

2) Можно кастомизировать infoWindow, например, как [вот тут](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) - пример от Google. Требует больше кода, но зато работать должно ок.

3) для стилей вместо infoWindow можно попробовать [**infoBox**](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/reference.html), пример использования его [можно увидеть тут](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/examples/infobox-basic.html).

Comment: Нет вы не поняли, мне надо стили сделать другие а не внутриности поменять

Comment: я делал уже такое но очень и очень кастыльно, http://tisys.ru/contacts/ внизу карта, я ищу хороший код, может есть какие-нибуть методы специальные при помощи которых можно все это сделать

Comment: @Karalahti понял о чем вы, обновил.

Comment: О, суппер 3 пример нашел сам код как это делается. Спасибо!!!